# Replacing UPS of a CPU with whole home suppression (undervoltage) system

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, feedback, ups

I need a new UPS however the knowledge acquired in the last years is preventing me from getting one

I live in a large city (127v), and voltages rarely go above 130v, however it has happened at least 3 times in the last couple years, that we do get undervoltages (87v) and most UPS do not protect against this

Heres an example of an average day of my voltage in my system

[image]

Correct me if I am wrong:

Surge protectors only have polyswitch (Resettable PTCs Devices) between phase and neutral

UPS use batteries to generate a squared sine wave digitally for short periods of time, cheap brands might be as bad as a 4 step sine wave, while full sine wave ones are way too expensive

However I don't even think these things should exist,  for the fact that a PC power supply (And in theory most if not all good quality power supplies) should be able to tolerate ±15% voltage variations, protecting effectively from sudden power outages and voltage variations

Most of the UPS do not provide full sine wave, I would rather said they are even more harmful than helpful to electronics in general due to the production micro shorts/surges in the systems

So instead I'm really trying to find a "whole home" solution for single phase systems finding [THIS](http://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product-range-download/64332-square-d-hepd50-home-electronics-protective-device/)

And if i did my homework right, looks like there are no "whole home surge suppressors" and the ones that exist are just as expensive as a high end UPS, and literally "break" by "protecting your electronics"

It gets worse, apparently a "surge" (voltage) variation can come from anywhere, from an outlet or the power provider so, in order to be really safe i would have to put a surge protector in every single outlet and service entry of the home and all of them will fail eventually, making the process way too expensive so is there really no easy way around this mess?

[image]

I know i'm asking for something really strange, but i'm looking for a "resettable" way to shutdown my electrical system on undervoltages or overvoltages (just like a fuse would do on a short or a breaker by overheating or a GFCI by a ground fault)

any feedback is welcome

Comment: First of all you need to rethink if you need to protect the whole house, e.g. your water heater, house heater, and AC all takes several KW each and they are very very robust. Then you need to consider what to protect against: strong surge/cutoff for a few Milli-seconds or +-20% over/under voltage for a few seconds, or worse. The are all different.

Comment: Also all UPSes does protect against under voltage, at least the voltage drops below threshold, they will all switch to battery. Some better ones("online" type) do AC-DC-AC conversion could also correct under-voltage before the threshold is reached.

Comment: And most modern switch mode power supplies, like laptop chargers, phone chargers, PCs, does have a very wide input range. 100V-240V is very common, some even do 90V-250V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with a "whole-home UPS" is that a common household uses a very wide variety of electrical appliances and devices with wildly different tolerances. What would fry one device is perfectly normal for another.

As a general principle, a protection device "downstream" of multiple devices with different operating principles, power consumption, etc. will be less effective at protecting **all** of the downstream devices, compared to a larger number of protection devices that are specifically designed for the acceptable electrical characteristics expected of a small number of specific electrical devices.

Uninterruptible Power Supplies for computers are pretty good at protecting electronic devices like PCs, laptops, monitors, and printers, because these devices are pretty similar in their tolerances and consumption.

GFCI devices in bathrooms are designed specifically to break the circuit in the case of human electrocution by appliances commonly used in the bathroom, like hair dryers and electric razors.

The most energy-intensive components of a modern household, like whole-home A/C units, often have built-in protection circuitry (assuming they're fairly modern in design) that is designed to protect these higher consumption devices.

If it were possible to accurately detect any dangerous situation that could damage a device from far upstream of that device, then it would be common to have whole-house "UPS" devices that would protect electronics, and it would be possible to have power generation stations equipped with devices to protect customers' electronics without individual customers having to install anything. But this is clearly not possible, because the momentary and localized surge that could destroy your PC is not detectable by an upstream power station's high-voltage equipment.

Time also matters a lot: the amount of time that is allowed to pass during which the improper voltage is applied, determines whether the computer / human / dog / whatever experiences no permanent damage; a little damage; or blows up in a shower of sparks.

The closer the protection system is to the device, the faster it can react. Even though current travels through wires at a large fraction of the speed of light, to maximize the protection of your devices / people, you want the protection system to be right there where it can shut off the power in just a few milliseconds, or disconnect from the mains and switch to batteries, in the case of a UPS.

Also, pure sine wave UPSes aren't that expensive. Most switching power supplies for computers won't even **work** with a UPS that doesn't produce a very smooth sine wave using a high frequency switching regulator (transistor-based). The real expensive UPSes are the "online" ones, whose power delivery to the downstream devices is completely decoupled from the mains (the mains are purely used to charge the batteries and a completely separate power regulator is provided to deliver clean power from the batteries to the computer).

So-called "line-interactive" UPSes are more efficient than online PSUs, don't wear down the batteries as fast, and are cheaper. You can find line-interactive PSUs both with and without pure sine wave capability. To drive a good, modern desktop PSU it definitely has to be pure sine wave, but that only adds about $30 to the cost in my experience.

Lastly -- if you're looking to buy a whole house UPS and you actually expect it to be effective for all of your power outlets, you should understand that the cost of such a thing would be much, much higher than even a very good single-computer UPS, even if these devices were on the market. They would have to anticipate dealing with a much wider variety of voltages and currents, both normal and abnormal, and not break themselves or allow any downstream devices to receive unsafe voltage or current. That's a very hard problem to solve, if it can be solved at all, and I don't imagine the cost would be at all comparable to even an excellent quality online PSU with a huge battery.

You would probably be much better served just educating yourself about the types of UPS out there; what they do; and how to find one that does what you want and fits within your budget. That is beyond the scope of this answer, however.